# Дизайн взаимодействия классов: агрегирование или дубликаты?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, дизайн

У меня есть 2 класса:

```
class RecTarget : public Target /* Абстрактный */
{ /* Точки расположены в форме Прямоугольника */

  std::set<Point> Set;
  /* Множество позволяет быстро ответить:
   * "Было ли попадание в цель?" - в точку из Target
   */

  /* ... */
};
```

Есть class Target, хранит Points, в которые Actor должен попасть. И class Target может ответить быстро, попал он или нет.

```
class Moves
{ std::map< Point*, std::list<WayToGetTheHit> > hmoves;
  /* Следит и сохраняет движения, приведшие к попаданию,
   * для каждой точки Point из Target.
   */

   Target* target; /* Использовать агрегирование? Каким образом? */
   /* ... */
};
```

Есть class Moves, для каждого удачного попадания сохраняет способ его достижения: движения Аctor'а, время и т.д. для дальнейшего анализа. Moves хранит для каждой точки Point Target'а попадания в сортированном списке std::list.

Озадачен я тем, что Target хранит Points и Moves должен хранить (те же) Points, соответственные Target'у. Я могу подать все точки в конструктор Moves в один момент и забыть про Target, но это неправильно логически. Мне нужна какая-то связь между этими классами, чтобы обеспечить разделение между ними данных.

Как лучше это реализовать?

Использовать агрегирование, чтобы точки Moves ссылались на точки Target (указатель `Point*` на `Target->Set->Point`) (в случае если Target'ы могут быть разными (наследование) - это должен быть *указатель*? - это мне не очень нравится)?

Или лучше просто хранить *дубликаты* Points (мне тоже не очень нравится)?

Может, есть дизайн правильней и лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь можно использовать разделяемые указатели на `Point`. Они избавят от необходимости думать про ответственность какого-либо объекта за удаление точек.

В Qt - `QSharedPointer<const Point>`, в стандартной библиотеке c++11 - `std::shared_ptr<const Point>`.

```
class RecTarget : public Target /* Абстрактный */
{ /* Точки расположены в форме Прямоугольника */

  std::set<std::shared_ptr<const Point> > Set;
...

class Moves
{ std::map< std::shared_ptr<const Point>, std::list<WayToGetTheHit> > hmoves;
```

Если вы используете c++11, для hmoves можно выбрать `std::unordered_map`, чтобы уйти от непонятной логики сравнения этих указателей (поскольку `std::map` сортирует значения по ключам). Правда, в этом случае очевидно придётся написать однометодный класс хэширования `std::hash<std::shared_ptr<Point> >`, но тут чего-то сложного нет.

Сами указатели на точки могут создаваться в другом месте и лишь передаваться для хранения как в `Moves`, так и в `Target`.

Прибавка `const` к классу шаблона гарантирует неизменность значения, на которое ссылается хранимый указатель. (Очевидно, и `Target`, и `Movies` не должны менять точки)